# bash script failing with additional charactors "\r"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, wsl-2

I'm running a script from Ubuntu 22 (WSL), and it was functioning OK until it suddenly stopped.

This script connects to  remote servers and collects data via ssh using ssh-pass the code with the issue listed below.

```
for IP in `cat $1`
do

        SERVERVER=`eval "export SSHPASS='""$(echo $password  )""'";sshpass -e ssh  $username@$IP -o "ConnectTimeout 3" "uname -sn"`

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
```

$1 - IP list

The issue is ssh connection fail due to additional characters "$" and "\r"

```
++ sshpass -e ssh $'mynewuser@192.168.10.4\r' -o 'ConnectTimeout 3' 'uname -sn'
+ SERVERVER=
+ '[' 255 == 0 ']'
```

I tried dos2unix but still same.

Expected

```
++ sshpass -e ssh 'mynewuser@192.168.10.4' -o 'ConnectTimeout 3' 'uname -sn'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `sshpass` so I can't say anything about the validity of the command-line and options itself, but I would separate the commands and remove the `eval`:

```bash
export SSHPASS="$password"
SERVERVER="$(sshpass -e ssh "$username@$IP" -o "ConnectTimeout 3" "uname -sn")"
```

The rouge `\r` could be removed with `tr`:

```
for IP in $(tr -d '\r' < "$1")
do
    ...
done
```

Comment: Thank you, its actually issue with input file , not sure how it converted to dos

Comment: @vijayedm You're welcome! Perhaps it was edited by someone using a Windows-editor.

Answer (score 3):

The trace is pretty obvious:

```
 ++ sshpass -e ssh $'mynewuser@192.168.10.4\r' -o 'ConnectTimeout 3' 'uname -sn'
```

So you have a carriage return character after the IP address. You get the IP address from

```
cat $1
```

which means that the file named by `$1` has a carriage return. Since `$1` is the first named parameter to your script, it means that this file is in error.

Either pass a different (and correct) file to your script or remove the carriage returns from that file.

An alternative would be to manually remove the carriage return(s) from the IP address in your script:

```
IP=${IP//$'\r'/}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing IP , the input file changed to dos